# Write in a text file without overwriting in fs node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How I can add text in my file but without overwriting the old text. I use the module fs (node js)

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
fs.writeFileSync("file.txt", 'Text', "UTF-8",{'flags': 'w+'});
```

any suggestion and Thanks.

Comment: I know this question had already been answered, but if anyone needs more information on how to read/write files with node just check out this tutorial: http://4dev.tech/2015/09/node-js-tutorial-reading-and-writing-files/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check the flags here: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback - you are currently using `w+` which:

> 'w+' - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).

You should use `a` instead:

> 'a' - Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not exist.
>
> 'ax' - Like 'a' but opens the file in exclusive mode.
>
> 'a+' - Open file for reading and appending. The file is created if it does not exist.
>
> 'ax+' - Like 'a+' but opens the file in exclusive mode.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer,

I found a solution,
I use this code :

    `fs.appendFileSync("file.txt", 'My Text \n', "UTF-8",{'flags': 'a+'});`

Comment: this doesn't seem to explain how to avoiding writing to a file if it already exists...?

Comment: NOTE: On Linux, positional writes don't work when the file is opened in append mode. The kernel ignores the position argument and always appends the data to the end of the file.

Answer (score 14):

Use fs.appendFile, that will just append the new information!

```
fs.appendFile("file.txt", 'Text',function(err){
if(err) throw err;
console.log('IS WRITTEN')
});
```