# Node createWriteStream Grunt Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have started to dabble around a bit with trying to use node to update html file contents at the end of the file - it is a template file in my Grunt file. The problems I am having:

1. I am using this code to update the end of the file with the package.json version:

   `appVersion = fs.createWriteStream('./src/file.html', {'flags' : 'a'});`

   `appVersion.write(grunt.file.readJSON('package.json').version);`

The only problem is that when I run grunt, it adds it to the end of the file every time I run grunt. Is there a way to have the version removed before I then write it again?

Thank you for any help on this.

**Update** - This goes along with [Write in a text file without overwriting in fs node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324797/write-in-a-text-file-without-overwriting-in-fs-node-js). I am wondering and trying to learn if using "a+" for the flag will let me delete the version and then append it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing the version over and over in your source file, I would rather suggest having a "marker" in your source file and process that file to its destination replacing the marker with the actual value.

That is (using grunt-template):

Have your html source file like that:

```
<html>
<body>
<%= pkg.version %>
</body>
</html>
```

In your gruntfile config:

```
grunt.initConfig({pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')}
```

Now, when you are going to copy your html file to its final destination, process its content using grunt-template:

```
  grunt.config('copy.myhtml', {
    options: {
      processContent: function (content, srcpath) {
        return grunt.template.process(content);
      }
    },
    files: [{src: "src/index.html", dest: "output/index.html"}]
  });
```

Now call grunt copy:myhtml and that should do.

I'm aware this is not exactly what you had in mind, but it's likely a better workflow, more in line with the tools' philosophy (eg: grunt), and the result is what you wanted (package version in the html file).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This I will probably go with if I am not able to do it with the above option. I am trying to figure out if I use "a+" instead, will it allow me to delete and then write again? If not, I will go with the grunt-template ( which I was using before ).

Comment: Using a+ doesn't change your problem - it just means your file will be opened for reading AND appending. What you want to do is: read its content, then parse the content, then detect the section where the old version is, then replace it with the new version, then write the file again... Modes (a/a+) are not magic ;)