# JSON to backup JSON

Tags: json, node.js, fs

I want to use fs to backup one JSON file to the next heres my code

```
function saveWorld() {
  for (i = 0; i < worlds.length; i++) {
   fs.writeFileSync("./save", JSON.stringify(worldnames), "utf8")
   fs.writeFileSync("./save", JSON.stringify(worlds), "utf8")
  }
 }
```

and it overwrites the first file can anyone help me prevent this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write in a text file without overwriting in fs node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324797/write-in-a-text-file-without-overwriting-in-fs-node-js)

Comment: Do you want to write `worldnames` to one  and `worlds` to another file, you do you want them in the same file?  And once you've done it, how do you plan to read this data?

Comment: i want to write both files to one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want second call to be `fs.appendFile()`

Comment: if this solves your problem, [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)